# Why do we say UX for User Experience rather than UE?

Tags: terminology, ux-field, history

The term User Experience goes back to Don Norman sometime in the early 90s.

But where did the abbreviation UX, rather than UE, come from?

I'm guessing that it was influenced by the release of Windows XP [("short for Experience"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP)) which came out in late 2001).

I came across a copy of the UPA Magazine from Winter 2002 which is called 'User Experience' and a page in this gives "The UX Book Selection" - so UX rather than UE was being used then.

Can anyone provide some earlier history or references?

Comment: All I can say is that your guess is definitely not right, here is another older popular source that uses x rather than e to denote experience: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25901/who-popularised-the-abbreviation-of-xp-for-experience-points-was-it-basic-dd

Comment: Interesting: so it looks like it might have come through the paper based and then computerised gaming route.

Comment: not even necessarily, just hit me that phonetically x is eks and e is just e at best and experience starting with eksp it makes sense to abbreviate it with x instead of e.

Comment: @adrianh, I don't think this is a duplicate.  That question is about the origin of the term "user experience"; this one is about the origin of the abbreviation "U**X**".

Comment: The linked question is about the term User Experience, this question is about the abbrevation UX. So it's not a duplicate.

Comment: It's EXTREEEEEEEEEME!

Comment: The letter "X" has been deemed "sexy" by advertisers in the 1970s (see for example, the rebranding of Standard Oil > Esso > Exxon), so people will tend to use it if they can. Also UX is more alliterative to what the acronym expands to than *you-ee*.

Comment: XP has been used in gaming circles for years, one could call Stack Exchange rep XP

Comment: Is this really a UX question? Seems much more of an English.se question. :)

Comment: It looks like 'used in gaming' is the answer Toni.  I'll tick that as the answer if anyone would like to post it as an answer not a comment.

Comment: XML (eXtensible Markup Language) predates Windows XP (1997 vs 2001) and uses the same abbreviation rule.

Comment: I'd noted that below:  it looks like the preference for the X came from the gaming community - and then when games went digital so did the X.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/XMakesAnythingCool

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I find it glaring that the sound of the letter 'X' (ex) is the same as the opening sound in **ex**perience, whereas the letter 'E' sounds like the start of **i**nternational.

So I think that sound-wise, UX is closer to User Experience than UE.

Just to support this:

[image: A cloth tag showing the size XL]

Extra large is marked 'XL' and not 'EL'.

Also, the sound of UE (U-yi) reminds of GUI (Gu-yi) and UI (which some pronounce yu-aye, while others U-yi - just like UE).

Comment: also XML, FX, Xmas …

Comment: Good point about XML ( EXtensible Markup Language ) which Wikipedia gives as introduced in 1996.  So the dropping the E idea was around at this point in the tech world.

Comment: I agree that seeing E in XL sort of situations would just look weird. X just seems to make sense for EX words. It could be said its just due to a quirk of English and our fear of leaving X's out in the open (where the children can see them) that means there's an E there.

Comment: I agree with everything except for "e" being the same sound as the i in international

Answer (score 9):

### 1. UE was used before UX

This is the first recorded instance of "User Experience" as a job role that I could find and it came from an Apple document from 1995...

> This office has introduced a new procedure for products, which starts with the creation of a "**User Experience** Requirements Document" (**UE**RD).
>
> -- source: [Don Norman, Jim Miller, Austin Henderson  -- Apple Computer, Inc.](http://www.sigchi.org/chi95/proceedings/orgover/dan_bdy.htm)

### 2. UX has less competition than UE

A single abbreviation can mean many different things and a quick search reveals [47 definitions for UE](http://www.abbreviations.com/UE) and only [9 definitions for UX](http://www.abbreviations.com/UX)

### 3. UX sounds better

Saying the first syllable of each word **U**ser **Ex**perience sounds like **UX**.

Apple has a job listing for a [UI/UX Developer](https://jobs.apple.com/us/search?jobFunction=DES#specs&ss=UX&t=0&so=&pN=0&openJobId=38423176) (at the time of this posting).  If they really did coin the term "User Experience" using the initials UE back in 1995 they seem to agree that UX is the term professionals understand and use today.

Comment: I admit that this conclusion is only conjecture, however, it does seem more likely than this other possible scenario...  One day a dyslexic Windows XP engineer interpreted UE as EU and thought, "Why is the European Union suing Microsoft for bundling their browser into Windows XP?" and then decided to get back at them by creating a Windows UX - User eXperience job position.

Comment: On the competition front, you also have “CXO” avoiding clear confusion with “CEO”.

Answer (score 2):

The earliest historical reference I could find on the etymology of UX is from a [2005 UX Week conference by Adaptive Path](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jmspool/sets/804956/), which has hosted the conference each year since. (The 2005 conference is no longer listed on their website; the link resolves to photos from the event.)

Most other references to the term begin in 2008. (Search for the term " UX" on wired.com, oldest first. After the Vaio reviews, the UX references begin on 8/10/08.) Don't forget to put the space before UX in the search and enclose it in quotes.

For more research, the founder of Adaptive Path, Mike Kuniavsky, wrote [this paper](http://www.orangecone.com/UXWeek_presentation_0.1.pdf) in 2001, describing user experience, but the paper does not use the acronym UX. If you are feeling particularly curious, you could ask him more about the etymology of the term.

Comment: It became more widely used around 2007 / 2008 when (in the UK) there was a sudden increase in the number of people interested in interface design.  This may in turn have been to do with the broadening in of the scope of interface design to include Mobile Phone Apps ( the first iPhone came out in 2007 ).

Answer (score 0):

I like all aforementioned answers. I would also add that in many instances we are using "X" to show power/importance of a concept. We may find a number of websites and companies who are trying to select a word for their brands that contains X to empower their branding.
Besides, this is kinda formal in computer science to replace "ex" with X, for those who are familiar with Extreme Programming (XP) this argument makes sense.